# Unable to update view on array update in ng-repeat ($scope.$apply() ) does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

The view does not update if the array is updated inside a function. Although, if I console.log the array after array.push then it shows the updated array. I have tried $scope.apply() inside $timeout still it does not work.

**JavaScript**:

```
$scope.openQuestions = [];

$scope.openQuestions.push({value: '1', question: 'abc1'});

$timeout(function() {        

  $scope.$apply(function() {            
    $scope.fetchOpen();      
  });

}, 500);

console.log($scope.openQuestions); //shows the updated value

$scope.fetchOpen = function() {
  $scope.openQuestions.push({value: '2', question: 'abc2'});
}
```

**Html**

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat = "question in openQuestions">
 <p>{{question.question}} </p>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Result: abc1

Comment: The $timeout service automatically calls $apply so it is unnecessary and likely to cause [Error: $rootScope:inprog
Action Already In Progress](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog)

Comment: You should check the developer console log to see there is no error because of the  redundant $apply georgeawg is talking about and remove the $apply.

Comment: Unable to verify a problem. Works fine in this [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/Jo8CBXtbgoFp4ydsQMYE?p=preview).

Comment: @georgeawg Yes it works most of the times, but it does not work few times in different machines, actually, that array is just a sample I have multiple objects inside that array, and the length is around 100.

Comment: @georgeawg This array gets updated on web push notification click and shows the updated array inside the developer console after the click, but sometimes it does not update the view, therefore, It's not stable.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: **Ensure that the example actually reproduces the problem!** If you inadvertently fixed the problem while composing the example but didn't test it again, you'd want to know that before asking someone else to help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the use of the [Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push?v=control) function:

```
 $scope.openQuestions = $scope.openQuestions.push({value: '2', question: 'abc2'});
```

As said in the docs:

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and
>   returns the new length of the array.

It returns the length of the array and you put it in the reference variable that hold the array and effectively overrun it.

Instead, just use the push without setting the array again:

```
$scope.fetchOpen = function() {
  $scope.openQuestions.push({value: '2', question: 'abc2'});
}
```

Comment: Thanks @elpddev for your views, I have updated the question, it still does not update the HTML

Answer (score 0):

**@Sumit Rana** Is the code which you posted exactly how you are using it, or did you strip it down for posting it here? The reason why I'm asking is, that I had nearly exactly the same issue, except that I was not using a timer like you.  Instead I had a simple function which should just add an element to an array. I was playing around with all those fiddles out there which worked fine. Unfortunately in my case `ng-repeat` did not update. Then it turned out that the reason was correlated to my (fairly complex) `ng-repeat` statement:

```
<tr ng-repeat="cmr in cmrs | orderBy:crit:rev:sortByCrit | filter:{selected:search_selected, ip:search_ip, name:search_name, location:search_location}:false as filtered" class="row-eq-height">
```

The problem was that I was reading all attributes from a file, except the "selected" attribute. This attribute I'm initializing after loading the data. Unfortunately I forgot to do this initialization as well after changing the array. Thus this attribute was not existing in the scope and I always got an empty list.